# How to to select records in jquery data table pagination

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, struts2-jquery

Hi am trying to send all records with in a jquery data table when i click select all(hyperlink) option or i want particular records in particular pages(using checkbox) to server class but the problem is  when i click form submit button I.e Export PDF am getting only the records from current page even though records selected in other pages in jquery data table pagination

**Why selected records in different pages of jquery data table are not sent to java class**

https://jsfiddle.net/4n5o3r3e/

```
<s:form id="downloadStudentDetailsForm" action="downloadStudentDetails" theme="css_xhtml" cssClass="form-horizontal">

<div class="dataTable_wrapper">
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTS">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><a href="#" id="bas">Select all</a></th>
<th>Student Name</th>
<th>Parent Phone</th>   
<th>Parent Email</th>                                                       
<th>ReferenceID</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<s:iterator value="studentRecords">
<tr>
<td><s:checkbox name="students" cssClass="case chkPassport" fieldValue="%{studentname+' '+phone+' '+email+' '+ref}"  /></td>                                                            
<td><s:property value="studentname" /></td> 
<td><s:property value="phone" /></td>   
<td><s:property  value="email"></td>                                                        
<td><s:property value="ref" /></td>
 </tr>
 </s:iterator>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-1 ">
 <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-success" value="Export to Excel" id="exl" action="downloadStudentsListINExcel" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-3 ">
 <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-danger" value="Export to PDF" id="pdf" action="downloadStudentsListInPDF" />
 </div>                                             </s:form>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what is the desired behaviour of the program? And please edit the first paragraph, because it is impossible to get what do you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly, you want to select all rows when clicking on the select all button and send the count of the selected rows to the server.

Here is a **[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2nk5eLm5/4/)**.

So I made this(you will figure out how to send the count to the server) using the datatables api:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table =  $('#example').DataTable();

$("#selectall").click(function() {
    var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();

   debugger;
   if($('input:checked', rows).length == rows.length){
     $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', false);
    }
    else{
     $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', true);
   }


$('#dvcount').html($(rows).find("input:checked").length);

$("body").on("change","input",function() {

    var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
    $('#dvcount').html($(rows).find("input:checked").length);

});

  } );
```

Comment: its displaying count correctly but  why am not able send all the data to server still its sending current page itself

Comment: You should ask a new question specific for that issue. @jancypradeep

Answer (score 0):

I went about solving it differently but I think the answer above is the most elegant. I looked at the underlying data and changed that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let runningTotal = 0;
  let table = $('#example').DataTable();
  $("#selectall").click(function() {
    if (runningTotal == table.rows().count()) {
      table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        let clone = table.row(rowIdx).data().slice(0);
        clone[[clone.length - 1]] = '<input type="checkbox" class="record">'
        table.row(rowIdx).data(clone);
      });
    } else {
      table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        let clone = table.row(rowIdx).data().slice(0);
        clone[[clone.length - 1]] = '<input type="checkbox" class="record" checked="checked">'
        table.row(rowIdx).data(clone);
      });
    }
    runningTotal = 0;
    table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
      var data = this.data();
      if ($(data[data.length - 1]).prop("checked")) {
        runningTotal++
      }
    });
    $('#dvcount').html(runningTotal);
  });
  $('#example tbody').on("click", ".record", function() {
    let clone = table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data().slice(0);
    let checkbox = clone[clone.length - 1];
    if ($(checkbox).prop("checked")) {
      clone[[clone.length - 1]] = '<input type="checkbox" class="record">'
    } else {
      clone[[clone.length - 1]] = '<input type="checkbox" class="record" checked="checked">';
    }
    table.row($(this).closest('tr')).data(clone);
    runningTotal = 0;
    table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
      var data = this.data();
      if ($(data[data.length - 1]).prop("checked")) {
        runningTotal++
      }
    });
    $('#dvcount').html(runningTotal);
  });
  $("#export").on("click", function() {
    let exportedRows = [];
    table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
      let data = table.row(rowIdx).data()
      if ($(data[data.length - 1]).prop("checked")) {
        exportedRows.push(data.slice(0, -1));
      }
    });
    console.log(exportedRows);
  });
});
```

This is a [working](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/c85gc39f/) JSFiddle.

Comment: can we use  struts tag like <s:checkbox class=record/>   clone[[clone.length - 1]] = '<input type="checkbox" class="record">' instead of html tage

Comment: I think a far better solution, and one I've used before is to grab each row's data when it is selected and add it to an array variable which you then send to the server... I guess both @offir-peer and I have provided an answer, his seems much more elegant than mine, but mine does have a way of retrieving the data in the `click` event on the `export` button.